# How do we think about absences?

Tags: phenomenology

> The notion of intentional content as distinct from intentional object
> is also important in relation to the issue of thought about and
> reference to non-existent objects. Examples of this include perceptual
> illusions, thought about fictional objects such as Hamlet or Lilliput,
> thought about impossible objects such as round-squares, and thought
> about scientific kinds that turn out not to exist such as phlogiston.
> What is common to each of these cases is that it seems possible to
> have meaningful experiences, thoughts and beliefs about these things
> even though the corresponding objects do not exist, at least not in
> any ordinary sense of ‘exist’.

Ref: https://iep.utm.edu/huss-int/

Can the same be said of the non-existence, e.g. absence, of non-existent objects, that it has a noesis and noema? Does that absence of something have a way of appearing, in the same manner that the moon can appear half or full, or we can think of Mark Twain as Samuel Clemens?

Comment: work *with* me here, please. i don't see what is wrong with the question, what mistake i've made other than asked something fringe

Comment: do you really not understand the question, or is it just that you cannot answer it? i reached 2 people, then got a downvote, and still reached 2 people. someone had gone away, tried to google an answer, failed to, and so downvoted... if these were googlable questions i would not need to ask them,

Comment: Source: https://iep.utm.edu/huss-int/. Perhaps _the absence_ is the object in this case, but not sure about it (know too few about Husserl). +1

Comment: thanks! would be amazing if we don't we just get on with it... but not likely @RodolfoAP i guess it's much more likely to be a quality of Being

Comment: I've added the reference. Context may help some readers.

Comment: In Husserl's terms, we have intentional acts "founded" on other intentional acts, e.g. acts of comparison of two objects. Absences are just a special case of those, where arrangements with and without the item are compared, they "appear" in their noetic superposition. See [SEP, Holes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/holes/) for a special case of absences that received much attention.

Comment: This question might be useful https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/49592/questions-on-non-ontology